# Empty received value from evaluateJavascript function in Android 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using webview with Android 4.4(Kitkat) to view htmls, and using javascript for searching, highlighting and so on. When I equal string selected by string s inside onReceiveValue the selected still empty so how can i get string s from onReceiveValue out to my android code

This is my code:

```
     String selected="";
     webview.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function(){" 
       + "var txt = window.getSelection();"
      +"return txt;" + 
       "})();" ,new ValueCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
      Log.d("LogName", s); //s is empty!
       selected=s; 
     }} 
     );
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is window.getSelection() returns an object, which you need to cast to a string.

```
theWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function(){"
        + "var selObj = window.getSelection();"
        + "var selTxt = selObj.toString();"
        + "return selTxt;"
        + "})();" ,new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("LogName", s); //s is NOT empty!
    }}
);
```

Comment: Is this mean that i can equal s by outer string value in my class?